# Curved image bottom with shadow

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get this effect in Swift, tried many ways, UIBezierPath and so on, but nothing gets even closer to what I want to achieve. I'm interested in the bottom part of the image, that curve + shadow.

[image]

The best result I got with a UIBezierPath that cuts a view I placed on the bottom of the image. But then I can't put the shadow in there.  So, any other ideas ? Thanks !

PS: I didn't like the approach I took with my code so I didn't want to post it, but anyway, here it is:

- I put a white UIView on top of the image, on the bottom of it and 'cut' through it like this:

```
    let freeform = UIBezierPath()
    freeform.move(to: .zero)
    freeform.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: viewArch.width / 2, y: viewArch.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: viewArch.width / 4, y: viewArch.height))
    freeform.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: viewArch.width, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: viewArch.width * 0.75, y: viewArch.height))
    freeform.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewArch.width, y: viewArch.height))
    freeform.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: viewArch.height))
    freeform.addLine(to: .zero)
    freeform.close()
        
    let maskLayerA = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayerA.path = freeform.cgPath
    viewArch.layer.mask = maskLayerA
```

This results in something like:

[image]

But I used the path on my white view, not on the image, so no idea how to put now a shadow.

I outlined the viewArch here, just to be clear:

[image]

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, I added the code, not sure if I can put the shadow with this approach.